# PHP Registration form error on 13th line

Tags: php, syntax-error, registration

i've been trying to fix this error past 4 hours now, and i lost my hopes to do it on my own, so i've getting this error:

```
Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '||' (T_BOOLEAN_OR) in D:\xampp\htdocs\Login system\includes\signup.inc.php on line 13
```

How to get it fixed? I overlooked everywhere cuz i knew somewhere could be some left unclosed brackets.

And heres my php code, HELP ALLERT :<

```
<?php

if (isset($_POST['submit'])) {

    include_once 'dbh.inc.php';

    $uid = mysqli_real_escape_string($conn, $_POST['uid']);
    $pwd = mysqli_real_escape_string($conn, $_POST['pwd']);
    $email = mysqli_real_escape_string($conn, $_POST['email']);

    //Error Handlers
    //check for empty fields
    if (empty($uid) || empty(email) || empty($pwd)) {
        header("Location:  ../signup.php?signup=empty");
        exit();
    } else {
        //Check if input characters are valid
        if (!preg_match("/^[a-zA-Z*$/]", $uid)) {
            header("Location:  ../signup.php?signup=empty");
            exit();
        } else {
        //Check if email is valid
        if (!filter_var($email, FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL))
            header("Location:  ../signup.php?signup=empty");
            exit();
        } else {

            $sql = "SELECT * FROM users WHERE user_uid='$uid'";
            $result = mysql_query($conn, $sql);
            $resultCheck = mysqli_num_rows($result);

            if($resultCheck > 0) {
                header("Location:  ../signup.php?signup=usertaken");
                exit();
            } else {
                //Haching the password
                $hashedPwd = password_hash($pwd, PASSWORD_DEFAULT);
                //Insert the user into the database
                $sql = "INSERT INTO users (user_email, user_uid, user_pwd) 
                        VALUES ('$uid', '$email', '$hashedPwd' );";
                $result = mysqli_query($conn, $sql);
                header("Location:  ../signup.php?signup=success");
                exit();
            }
        }
    }
} else {
    header("Location:  ../signup.php");
    exit();
}
```

Comment: To make everything clear guys - This is my first PHP code on my own.

Comment: Check some syntax error like `empty(email)`

Comment: You are missing the `$` in front of email in the `empty(email)` check.

Comment: Some sensible code indentation would be a good idea. It helps us read the code and more importantly it will help **you debug your code**
[Take a quick look at a coding standard](http://www.php-fig.org/psr/psr-2/) for your own benefit. You may be asked to amend this code
in a few weeks/months and you will thank me in the end.

Answer (score -2):

You're writing the if-else statements the wrong way, the error you're getting is from the if statement with no opening and closing curly brackets, same goes for the other ones.
try this one:

```
    <?php
    include_once 'dbh.inc.php';
    if (!isset($_POST['submit'])) {
        header("Location:  ../signup.php");
        exit();
    }
    $uid = mysqli_real_escape_string($conn, $_POST['uid']);
    $pwd = mysqli_real_escape_string($conn, $_POST['pwd']);
    $email = mysqli_real_escape_string($conn, $_POST['email']);

    //Error Handlers
    //check for empty fields
    if (empty($uid) || empty(email) || empty($pwd)) {
        header("Location:  ../signup.php?signup=empty");
        exit();
    }

    if (!preg_match("/^[a-zA-Z*$/]", $uid)) {
        header("Location:  ../signup.php?signup=empty");
        exit();
    }

    if (!filter_var($email, FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL)){
        header("Location:  ../signup.php?signup=empty");
        exit();
    }


    if($resultCheck > 0) {
        header("Location:  ../signup.php?signup=usertaken");
        exit();
    }

    $sql = "SELECT * FROM users WHERE user_uid='$uid'";
    $result = mysql_query($conn, $sql);
    $resultCheck = mysqli_num_rows($result);

    if($resultCheck > 0) {
        header("Location:  ../signup.php?signup=usertaken");
        exit();
    }

    //Haching the password
    $hashedPwd = password_hash($pwd, PASSWORD_DEFAULT);
    //Insert the user into the database
    $sql = "INSERT INTO users (user_email, user_uid, user_pwd) VALUES ('$uid', '$email', '$hashedPwd' );";
    $result = mysqli_query($conn, $sql);
    header("Location:  ../signup.php?signup=success");
    exit();
```

Comment: @james yes their are missing brackets, take a look at the code and if you get confused, just copy and paste the code in your IDE, i don't get how your rep is 3425! ha

Comment: Yeah, the Fadi is right, it fixed my problem, and Dave was right too, i was missing "$" in front of email, but now i get one more problem... 

    "Object not found"

Comment: So I started looking at the braces and they look fine, but given the fact the missing braces are way down the code it would have been useful (necessary really) to explain this in your answer. Rather than just dump the OPs large amount of code and state "fixed it was some braces" and expect people to try to find where you fixed it, especially as it's not on "line 13" as per the error ;)

Comment: @MatasŽemaitis update your question

Comment: Okay James, sorry, i'm new here don't know everything yet.:)

Comment: How to close the question? :|

Comment: @MatasŽemaitis It's fine to ask your question :) just turned out to be a simple typo is all. A suggestion though, you should get an IDE (code editor) which has syntax highlighting, it shows you right there any issues, such as "*undefined constant email*" would have been highlighted and the missing braces etc. Saves you a lot of time :)

Comment: @James We normally close and delete TYPO's They rarely if ever are any use to others.